# How I can load csv data into hive using Spark dataframes?

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to load data from a csv file to Hive. I am using JAVA API of spark for doing that. I want to know how I can load data in hive using spark dataframes.
Here is what I try to make it using JSON:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
public class first {
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    String inputFileName = "samples/big.txt" ;
    String outputDirName = "output" ;

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("org.sparkexample.WordCount").setMaster("local");
    JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    SQLContext sc = new SQLContext(context);
    DataFrame input = sc.jsonFile(inputFileName);
    input.printSchema();
}
}
```

But don't know how to make it using csv. I have some idea about Spark-csv provided by databricks.
Kindly let me know how I can do it.

Comment: what version of spark are you using? also is your issue reading the csv or putting the resulting dataframe to hive?

Comment: you can use the spark-csv package to read the csv files into a `dataframe` and then use that to load it into hive table . https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

Comment: @AssafMendelson Spark version 1.6.0

Comment: @RajatMishra I am trying to that too. But don't understand the problem. First time working with Spar and java. Always had an interaction with Scala for spark but could not understand java.

Comment: sorry its 2.1.0 version I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On spark 2.x.x csv is built in (no need for package)
Try to read like this:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
.builder()
.appName("org.sparkexample.WordCount")
.master("local[*]") .
.enableHiveSupport()
.getOrCreate();
DataFrame input = spark.read.csv(inputFileName)
```

You can also add options for example:

```
DataFrame input = spark.read.option("header","true").csv(inputFileName)
```

will consider the first line to be a header and give the column names accordingly

Comment: Is this way I can write to hive? Actually reading was a problem now struggling with write.

Comment: you can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40122201/storing-a-dataframe-to-a-hive-partition-table-in-spark. I don't have hive configured so I can't check myself